# Calculating physical address from Logical Address

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

I have been give a page table logical address of 0011 0110 1010 1010 and have been told that there are 512 entries into this page table in which the frame number is two times smaller that the page number.

I have looked at previous posts but I am still not understanding what steps I must do in order to translate this logical address into physical address.

I understand that the logical address is 16 bits long and that the frame number is twice as small as the page number, however I am unsure what to do with this information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.